# Rails - How to re-render partial after Ajax GET method request

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

*Rail4,jQuery Ajax*

I need to display order for one day which chosen on - jQuery Datepicker.

I set up Ajax request and make some staff into my contoroller but I can't to make it works. Need advise.

**Order_controller**

```
def index
  @order = params[:date] ? Order.where(date: params[:date]) : Order.get_order_today
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # render index.html.haml 
  end
```

end

**order.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('#datepicker').datepicker dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: (dateStr) ->
     $.ajax ->
        type: "GET",
        url: "orders/index",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {date: dateStr}
        success: ->
           # Should i do something here for render default index view?
           console.log("everything is ok ;)")
```

**view/orders/index**

```
     #order.col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-8
        = render 'orders/order'
     #datepicker.col-xs-6.col-md-4.date-picker-div
```

**view/orders/_order**

```
%h3 Order info
%table.table.table-striped
  %tr
   %th Meal
   %th Price
 - if (!@order.nil?)
   - @order.products.each do |one_order|
     %tr
      %th=one_order.product_name
      %th=one_order.product_price
- else
     %tr
      %th no order yet
      %th
 - if (!@order.nil?)
    .col-md-8
       %span=link_to "Cancel order", delete_order_path(id: @order.id), method: :delete, :data => {:confirm => "You Sure?"},
                                          class: "btn btn-primary"
 - else
   .col-md-8
      %span=link_to "Create order", new_order_path , class: "btn btn-primary"
  .col-md-4.total-price-div
  %h4 Order coast: #{get_order_coast}
```

*- console show me that when day was chosen on datepicker*

**Console:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version work - order.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#datepicker').datepicker dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: (dateStr) ->
    $.get("orders", {dateStr})
```

**Now I need render order part:**

```
def index
  @order = params[:date] ? Order.where(date: params[:date]) : Order.get_order_today
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # render index.html.haml
  format.js
 end
end
```

**index.js.haml:**

```
:javascript
  $("#order").html('= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'orders/order') ');
```

But still,nothing happening with re-render my order info.

Answer (score 2):

Add in your controller index

```
   def index
     @order = params[:date] ? Order.where(date: params[:date]) : Order.get_order_today
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # render index.html.haml 
      format.js # render for the js request 
    end
  end
```

Then you will get response in your AJAX success or you can also create index.js.erb for get response

```
$("#activity_detail").html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'orders/order') %>');
```

Comment: i create index.js.haml    - but it still does not work..                                                                                           :javascript
   $("#order").html('= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'orders/order') ');

Comment: have you get response on index.js.haml

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how get ajax with params and re-render view. finally =)

**my coffee:**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#datepicker').datepicker( dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: (dateStr) ->
    $.ajax(
     url: "orders",
     data: {date: dateStr},
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
     success: (response) ->
       $('#order-block').html(response)
    )
   )
```

**index.js.haml**

```
:javascript
  $("#order").html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'orders/order', locals: { orders: @order } )}");
```

order_controller:

```
def index
if (!params[:date].nil?)
  @order = Order.find_by(date: params[:date])
else
  @order = Order.get_order_today
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # render index.html.haml
  format.js   # default render - index.js.haml
 end
end
```

**and i reorganized my view a little:**

```
 #order-block
  = render 'orders/order'
```